# Find all integer gaps in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database which is used to store information about different matches for a game that I pull in from an external source. Due to a few issues, there are occasional gaps (which could be anywhere from 1 missing ID to a few hundred) in the database. I want to have the program pull in the data for the missing games, but I need to get that list first.

Here is the format of the table:

```
id (pk-identity)  |  GameID (int)  |  etc.  |  etc.
```

I had thought of writing a program to run through a loop and query for each GameID starting at 1, but it seems like there should be a more efficient way to get the missing numbers.

Is there an easy and efficient way, using SQL Server, to find all the missing numbers from the range?

Comment: YOu are aware that with identity fields there will alawys be gaps, right? If a record is deleted or if the intial insert was rolled back you will have a gap.

Comment: Yes I understand how identity columns work, and if it was unclear I am referring to the GameID column.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea is to look at where the gaps start.  Let me assume you are using SQL Server 2012, and so have the `lag()` and `lead()` functions.  The following gets the next `id`:

```
select t.*, lead(id) over (order by id) as nextid
from t;
```

If there is a gap, then `nextid <> id+1`.  You can now characterize the gaps using `where`:

```
select id+1 as FirstMissingId, nextid - 1 as LastMissingId
from (select t.*, lead(id) over (order by id) as nextid
      from t
     ) t
where nextid <> id+1;
```

EDIT:

Without the `lead()`, I would do the same thing with a correlated subquery:

```
select id+1 as FirstMissingId, nextid - 1 as LastMissingId
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 id
              from t t2
              where t2.id > t.id
              order by t2.id
             ) as nextid
      from t
     ) t
where nextid <> id+1;
```

Assuming the `id` is a primary key on the table (or even that it just has an index), both methods should have reasonable performance.

Answer (score 2):

I like the "gaps and islands" approach. It goes a little something like this:

```
WITH Islands AS (
    SELECT GameId, GameID - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GameID) AS [IslandID]
    FROM dbo.yourTable
)
SELECT MIN(GameID), MAX(Game_id)
FROM Islands
GROUP BY IslandID
```

That query will get you the list of contiguous ranges. From there, you can self-join that result set (on successive IslandIDs) to get the gaps. There is a bit of work in getting the IslandIDs themselves to be contiguous though. So, extending the above query:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT GameId, GameId - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GameId) AS [rn]
    FROM dbo.yourTable
)
, cte2 AS (
    SELECT [rn], MIN(GameId) AS [Start], MAX(GameId) AS [End]
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY [rn]
)
,Islands AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [rn]) AS IslandId, [Start], [End]
  from cte2
)

SELECT a.[End] + 1 AS [GapStart], b.[Start] - 1 AS [GapEnd]
FROM Islands AS a
LEFT JOIN Islands AS b
    ON a.IslandID + 1 = b.IslandID
```

Answer (score 1):

[Numbers table!](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/dbo.numbers%20&%20dbo.calendar.sql)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.numbers (
   number int NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.numbers
ADD
   CONSTRAINT pk_numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (number)
     WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.numbers (number)
SELECT (a.number * 256) + b.number As number
FROM     (
        SELECT number
        FROM   master..spt_values
        WHERE  type = 'P'
        AND    number <= 255
       ) As a
 CROSS
  JOIN (
        SELECT number
        FROM   master..spt_values
        WHERE  type = 'P'
        AND    number <= 255
       ) As b
GO
```

Then you can perform an `OUTER JOIN` or EXISTS` between your two tables and find the gaps...

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.numbers
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   your_table
         WHERE  id = numbers.number
       )

-- OR

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.numbers
 LEFT
  JOIN your_table
    ON your_table.id = numbers.number
WHERE  your_table.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     SELECT * FROM #tab1
            id          col1
            ----------- --------------------
            1           a
            2           a
            3           a
            8           a
            9           a
            10          a
            11          a
            15          a
            16          a
            17          a
            18          a

 WITH cte (id,nextId) as
                (SELECT t.id, (SELECT TOP 1 t1.id FROM #tab1 t1 WHERE t1.id > t.id) AS nextId  FROM #tab1 t)

 SELECT id AS 'GapStart', nextId AS 'GapEnd' FROM cte
                WHERE id + 1 <> nextId

    GapStart    GapEnd
    ----------- -----------
    3           8
    11          15
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (This covers upto 10000 Ids starting from 1, if you need more you can add more to Numbers table below):

```
;WITH Digits AS (
    select Digit 
    from ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) as t(Digit))
,Numbers AS (
    select u.Digit 
          + t.Digit*10 
          + h.Digit*100 
          + th.Digit*1000
          + tth.Digit*10000 
          --Add 10000, 100000 multipliers if required here.
          as myId
    from Digits u
    cross join Digits t
    cross join Digits h
    cross join Digits th
    cross join Digits tth
    --Add the cross join for higher numbers 
    )
SELECT myId 
FROM Numbers
WHERE myId NOT IN (SELECT GameId FROM YourTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: we need to find the gap range in `id` field

```
SELECT * FROM #tab1

id          col1
----------- --------------------
1           a  
2           a  
3           a  
8           a    
9           a  
10          a  
11          a  
15          a  
16          a  
17          a  
18          a
```

Solution

```
WITH cte (id,nextId) as
(SELECT t.id, (SELECT TOP 1 t1.id FROM #tab1 t1 WHERE t1.id > t.id) AS nextId  FROM #tab1 t)

SELECT id + 1, nextId - 1 FROM cte
WHERE id + 1 <> nextId
```

Output

```
GapStart    GapEnd
----------- -----------
4           7
12          14
```